Blacklist and burninate the [learn-chinese] tag?
This is perhaps the least useful tag on the site: learn-chinese.  It has no discriminatory power: every single question can have this tag.  It's literally what the site is about.
There is learning to cover questions related to the learning process.
Question: Should we blacklist and burninate the [learn-chinese] tag?
We'd need to make sure the questions which only have the tag learn-chinese are retagged first.

It seems there's also a beginner tag; these are meta tags which have been generally discouraged Stack-Exchange-wide for years; see The Death of Meta Tags, 2010:

The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.


The site's not quite just about "learning Chinese" (as in going through a process of acquiring literacy and spoken skills). Nevertheless, I agree that the tag is extremely pointless.

You could also just merge the tag, eliminating a lot of work including retagging, etc.

I'm declaring the learn-chinese burninated.  There's one question left, but it's off-topic so I just downvoted it and it should get auto-deleted tomorrow morning (I think it kicks in 10am or 11am Beijing time).

I doubt it'll come back (since there's the learning tag), so there's probably no point in blacklisting it.

I guess we can eradicate it manually.  I don't think I've ever seen a poorly tagged question without other ways it can be improved, which we can do 顺便.
It's clearly something that new users find when asked to tag their questions.  Most users who use this tag have <200 rep.
I changed the tag description to say

PLEASE DON'T USE THIS TAG: every question is about learning Chinese. Please use [learning] for questions about the learning process.

